# phpMy Admin 4.8.4 export table as SQL is missing

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, export

How to create the well known export as SQL in latest phpMyAdmin ?
There is no choice for SQL anymore!

Comment: **Fixed after 4.8.4 version, download latest version**.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in the latest version of phpmyadmin (4.8.4), where SQL export is not available anymore.

The problem has been raised to phpmyadmin team and they are working on providing a solution for this. You can follow the progress [in this github issue](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14775).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to export is through CLI:

```
mysqldump -u user -p database t1 t2 ... > exported.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

export to SQL format not available for tables in 4.8.4 version.

I have completed this task by doing the following steps.

1. export the whole DB in SQL format then open that file.
2. Search the table name which you want to import.
3. Copy the queries(create table query and insert query) of that table, then simply run that SQL query where you want to import.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin(YOUR_PHP_VERSION)\libraries\classes\Display (Path where you have install wamp server)
2. open Export.php
3. look for line /* Scan for plugins */ (near 662)
4. check if the following lines are set or not.

   ```
    if (isset($_POST['single_table'])) {    
      $GLOBALS['single_table'] = $_POST['single_table'];      
    }  


    if (isset($_GET['single_table'])) {       
      $GLOBALS['single_table'] = $_GET['single_table'];      
   }
   ```

I was fetched the same issue, after applying the above solution I see `sql` option in the dropdown list. and successfully export table in sql format.